# How to remove multiple lists from the multiple lists?

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
l1 = [[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,4,6,7]]
l2 = [[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,4,6,7], [1,2,3,6,8], [1,2,3,0,9], [1,2,6,7,6]]
```

I want to create a new list `l3` that contains the items of `l2` that are not in `l1`. Something like this:

```
l3 = l2-l1
```

So, I am expecting an `l3` as:

```
l3 = [[1,2,3,6,8], [1,2,3,0,9], [1,2,6,7,6]]
```

How can I achieve that?
Any solution Using remove() or delete() in python..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove `l2` sublists that are in `l1` and create a new list with the remaining sublists, try this:

```
l1 = [[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,4,6,7]]
l2 = [[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,4,6,7], [1,2,3,6,8], [1,2,3,0,9], [1,2,6,7,6]]

for sub in l1:
    if sub in l2:
        l2.remove(sub)

l3 = l2[:]

>>> l1
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 4, 6, 7]]
>>> l2
[[1, 2, 3, 6, 8], [1, 2, 3, 0, 9], [1, 2, 6, 7, 6]]
>>> l3
[[1, 2, 3, 6, 8], [1, 2, 3, 0, 9], [1, 2, 6, 7, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
l3 = [lst for lst in l2 if lst not in l1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Build a set of tuples for the O(1) membership test. (In your trivial example, that would not be necessary, but I am assuming big lists.) Then filter via list comprehension.

```
>>> checker = set(map(tuple, l1))
>>> [l for l in l2 if tuple(l) not in checker]
[[1, 2, 3, 6, 8], [1, 2, 3, 0, 9], [1, 2, 6, 7, 6]]
```

Comment: you can probably gain more if you assume that `checker` gets *depleted* which seems to be the case.

Comment: After `[1,2,3,4,5]` is found on `l2` and skipped, `checker` could be updated to contain `[1,2,4,6,7]` **only**. I am assuming here that entries on `l2` are unique. Scaled up, the membership test would benefit from a smaller-sized `checker`.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis ok, I see what you mean. I can't make those assumptions without clarification from OP.

Comment: You are right; it would make the question a bit more interesting though.. Anyway, +1

Comment: @timgeb any other process using remove or delete functions in python

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
l1 = [[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,4,6,7]]
l2 = [[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,4,6,7], [1,2,3,6,8], [1,2,3,0,9], [1,2,6,7,6]]

l3=[]

for i in l2:
    if i not in l1:
        l3.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Itertool :

```
import itertools
k = l2+l1
k = sorted(k)
list(k for k,_ in itertools.groupby(k))
```

[itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)  offers the fastest and most powerful solutions to this kind of problems , and will be efficient in terms of time  , when the list size grows ,

And it's the pythonic way to achieve the solution , as the saying goes "When you are in Rome, Do like Romans."

Answer (score 0):

If order and types are not crucial, use [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) instead.  They are fast and resemble your examples:

```
set1 = {tuple(l) for l in l1}
set2 = {tuple(l) for l in l2}
set2 - set1
# {(1, 2, 3, 0, 9), (1, 2, 3, 6, 8), (1, 2, 6, 7, 6)}
```

The first two lines convert the lists into (unordered) sets of tuples, e.g.

```
{(1, 2, 4, 6, 7), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)}
{(1, 2, 4, 6, 7), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 0, 9), (1, 2, 3, 6, 8), (1, 2, 6, 7, 6)}
```

These forms allow set operations, i.e. one equivalent to the difference between `set2` and `set1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l1 = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,4,6,7]]
>>> l2 = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,4,6,7],[1,2,3,6,8],[1,2,3,0,9],[1,2,6,7,6]]
>>> for i in l1:
>>> if i in l2:
>>>     del l2[l2.index(i)]
>>> print(l2)
```